# Sorting groups of JMenuItems inside the same JMenu without sorting other JMenuItems

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jmenu

An application I'm working on let's users establish connections to some industry-specific Hardware. Those connections (IP/Host couplings) can be saved and given a name, and optionally a group attribute that will pair saved connections belonging to the same group.

I now have a JMenu that provides the user with all kinds of options to do with connections. The structure of the JMenu is as follows:

1. Establish new Connection
2. A JSeparator
3. 3 Standard revisor connection entries that always stay the same
4. JSeparator
5. **Multiple entries for the defined Connection-Groups**
6. JSeparator
7. **Multiple entries not belonging to a group**
8. JSeparator
9. Close Connection

The sorting algorithm I need would have to sort the groupped entries from 5. alphabetically and the ungroupped entries from 7. alphabetically, without sorting any other MenuItems. Basically, how do I sort sub-groups of MenuItems inside a JMenu without sorting all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used Swing, but I'm assuming you can store the string for each menu item's text in an array of Objects and render the menu items in a `for` loop.  You could then store 1, 3, and 9 as strings in the array, and 5 and 7 as ArrayLists of strings within the first array.  You could then insert a JSeparator between each item in the first array when you render it, making sure that each item is a string by using the `instanceof` keyword.  If the item is not an `instanceof` string and it is an `instanceof` ArrayList<String>, you could render a menu item for each string in that inner ArrayList.  You can sort the items in each inner ArrayList alphabetically using `Collections.sort(mainArray[indexesOfSubarrays])`.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if I can implement this idea directly due to the dynamic nature of the data, but this might be a good starting point to build a solution that works! I'll probably have to fill an ArrayList first and once that's fully built convert it to an Array. Was hoping for a less "hack-y" solution, but was already suspecting that such a solution might be the one haha. Thanks anyway and also for the edited tag aswell!

Comment: @yur you're welcome!  You could definitely use an ArrayList for 5 and 7, and the main array could still be an array.  Using an ArrayList for the whole thing could also work.  In that case, you could have a string be a delimiter that stands for "insert JSeparator here".  You could then sort the items in between the delimiters by adding them to a new ArrayList and sorting that.

Comment: Also a good idea! I'll go try some stuff out and if I come up with something that's not too specific to my data, I'll report back with my algorithm!